# How can I make Google API requests without Google's client libraries?

Tags: javascript, google-api, deno

I'm doing some analysis for a company I work for and I require using the Google Gmail API to see emails that have been sent to me.

My project is using Deno and as its a very new framework, Google doesn't have a third-party module to use with it. On the Google API documentation, all the quickstarts require using Google's libraries to authenticate and make requests.

I was wondering if there was a way to make Google API requests with simple `fetch` requests so I can just develop my own little module for making Google API requests. I couldn't find any information on the Google API website about what specific REST requests are made to authenticate with their API.

If this isn't possible, please let me know so I can think about converting all my code to Node.js (I really don't want to do this).

Comment: Why recreate the wheel? `Google Workspace quickstarts use the API client libraries to handle some details of the authentication and authorization flow. We recommend that you use the client libraries for your own apps. ` https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/nodejs

Comment: Because I'm using Deno (similar to Node.js, made by the same guy) and they don't have a Google SDK as of yet since its a very new framework. The rest of my project is already made heavily implementing Deno-specific modules, so, it would be a lot of work to rewrite it in Node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Gmail API Overview Guide](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides) for the guidance. You will be implementing your own OAUTH2 solution rather than using their premade client libraries. For details on how to do that, see [Using OAuth 2.0 for Web Server Applications](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server)

> OAuth 2.0 allows users to share specific data with an application
> while keeping their usernames, passwords, and other information
> private. For example, an application can use OAuth 2.0 to obtain
> permission from users to store files in their Google Drives.

Basically, your app's users will be prompted to allow your app access to their Google account with scope that includes Gmail data. You'll get handed a token that is used to make the REST calls.

Answer (score 1):

Google's SDK aren't doing anything magical. They're just fancy wrappers around a REST client.

You can look into the SDK source code to see exactly what they are doing. For example, here are the parameters you need for one of the calls: https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client/blob/2e3dbab2fe0a4fbc56f4a7135fcb873b34c78fe9/src/apis/gmail/v1.ts#L4490

You can see the exact specifics in the docs: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/list